# UWP Page navigation indentifier

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Hello in UWP I can navigate to another page like:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(AnotherPage), someObject);
```

and in `AnotherPage` if I want to retrieve the object:

```
protected override void OnNavigationTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    SomeObject someObject = (SomeObject) e.Parameter;
    //here I would like to know from what page I am navigating
}
```

Could you tell me how to find out from what page am I navigating? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When navigation is done, the previous page gets put on the Frame's BackStack, simply query that collection.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    SomeObject someObject = (SomeObject)e.Parameter;

    PageStackEntry previousPage = Frame.BackStack.Last();
    Type previousPageType = previousPage?.SourcePageType;

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```